# Is it true that the standard model does not predict the mass of the electron?

Tags: mass, electrons, standard-model

I read that the standard model has parameters that have to be put in such as the mass of the electron, because nobody has been able to calculate the mass of the electron. Is this true?

Comment: I advise removing everything after "is this true?". We prefer mainstream, clear questions here, less so things about your own pet ideas

Comment: please leave a link in a comment  if you post your model on another web page. I am curious to see how you reached that result.

Comment: The electron mass $m_e$ is one of the [19 parameters of the SM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#Theoretical_aspects).

Comment: More like an electron-higgs interaction term, but nonetheless. Successful calculation of the mass of the electron from fundamental principles would be considered a major advance in our understanding of the Universe.

Comment: @anna v - I posted the the derived equation at www.physicsdiscussionforum.org. I will add more details in the next few days. Buzz- thanks for the clear answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true.  There are a large number of parameters in the standard model that can only be fixed by experiment.  (Before the discover of neutrino masses, there were famously 19, but the neutrino sector introduces more.)  The electron mass is determined by the coupling of the electron field to the Higgs field and the parameters of the Higgs sector.  None of these is predicted a priori, and so we know their values only from experimental evidence.